# Can't remove the error message of Rendering Problems on my project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have my own project that i wrote 6 month ago. 
I open my android studio and update all possible updates on it.

I open the project and the android studio offer me to upgrade the project to API 23 - so i upgrade.

Now when i trying to see the designer of any activity - i can't see the GUI and i getting this error :

**"Rendering Problems Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or [later Install a supported JDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8)"**

I did all the instruction that was told in the attached link  -  and still nothing work and i still can't see the GUI of the activity when i trying to open it from the android studio.

Comment: Click on the letter N, next to the android icon in the Preview window and select API level 23 or lower. That should solve it

Comment: Thanks ! 
problem solved

Comment: I have posted Answer so that this can help other and you also upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **letter N**, next to the android icon in the Preview window and select **API level 23 or lower**. That should solve it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Android Studio on Windows after upgrading Java 7. I solved it by updating JAVA_HOME and Path environment variables to point to jdk1.8.